# It is necessary to close MongoDB Changestream after receiving and processing the event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, changestream

In Node js, assuming I want Changestream to be active and listen to any collection events.

After receiving and processing a new event, do I have to close the Changestream with the close() method?

Example for Changestram function:

```
const client = await getMongoClient();
    const heros = client
    .db("heros")
    .collection("marvel");
    const insert_pipeline = [
        {$match: {operationType: 'insert'}}
    ];

    let marvel = heros.watch(insert_pipeline);
    marvel.on("change", async (next) => {
    ….
    });
```

So, do I need to use  `await marvel.close()` method?